# In the category of sigma algebras, are all epimorphisms surjective?

Tags: ct.category-theory, boolean-algebras

Consider the category of abstract $\sigma$-algebras ${\mathcal B} = (0, 1, \vee, \wedge, \bigvee_{n=1}^\infty, \bigwedge_{n=1}^\infty, \overline{\cdot})$ (Boolean algebras in which all countable joins and meets exist), with the morphisms being the $\sigma$-complete Boolean homomorphisms (homomorphisms of Boolean algebras which preserve countable joins and meets).  If a morphism $\phi: {\mathcal A} \to {\mathcal B}$ between two $\sigma$-algebras is surjective, then it is certainly an epimorphism: if $\psi_1, \psi_2: {\mathcal B} \to {\mathcal C}$ are such that $\psi_1 \circ \phi = \psi_2 \circ \phi$, then $\psi_1 = \psi_2$.  But is the converse true: is every epimorphism $\phi: {\mathcal A} \to {\mathcal B}$ surjective?

Setting ${\mathcal B}_0 := \phi({\mathcal A})$, the question can be phrased as following non-unique extension problem.  If ${\mathcal B}_0$ is a proper sub-$\sigma$-algebra of ${\mathcal B}$, do there exist two $\sigma$-algebra homomorphisms $\psi_1, \psi_2: {\mathcal B} \to {\mathcal C}$ into another $\sigma$-algebra ${\mathcal C}$ that agree on ${\mathcal B}_0$ but are not identically equal on ${\mathcal B}$?

In the case that ${\mathcal B}$ is generated from ${\mathcal B}_0$ and one additional element $E \in {\mathcal B} \backslash {\mathcal B}_0$, then all elements of ${\mathcal B}$ are of the form $(A \wedge E) \vee (B \wedge \overline{E})$ for $A, B \in {\mathcal B}_0$, and I can construct such homomorphisms by hand, by setting ${\mathcal C} := {\mathcal B}_0/{\mathcal I}$ where ${\mathcal I}$ is the proper ideal
$$ {\mathcal I} := \{ A \in {\mathcal B}_0: A \wedge E, A \wedge\overline{E} \in {\mathcal B}_0 \}$$
and $\psi_1, \psi_2: {\mathcal B} \to {\mathcal C}$ are defined by setting
$$ \psi_1( (A \wedge E) \vee (B \wedge \overline{E}) ) := [A]$$
and
$$ \psi_2( (A \wedge E) \vee (B \wedge \overline{E}) ) := [B]$$
for $A,B \in {\mathcal B}_0$, where $[A]$ denotes the equivalence class of $A$ in ${\mathcal C}$, noting that $\psi_1(E) = 1 \neq 0 = \psi_2(E)$.  However I was not able to then obtain the general case; the usual Zorn's lemma type arguments that one normally invokes to give Hahn-Banach type extension theorems don't seem to be available in the $\sigma$-algebra setting.  I also played around with using the Loomis-Sikorski theorem but was not able to get enough control on the various null ideals to settle the question (some subtle issues reminiscent of "measurable selection theorems" seem to arise). However, Stone duality seems to settle the corresponding question for Boolean algebras.

Comment: Is it true that, if there's a homomorphism to some $\mathcal C$, then there's a homomorphism to $\mathbb F_2$; or might it be that a more exotic target is required?

Comment: I don't think homomorphisms to $\mathbb{F}_2$ suffice.  For instance if one takes the measure algebra ${\mathcal L}([0,1])/\sim$ (Lebesgue measurable subsets of $[0,1]$ modulo null sets) then there are no homomorphisms to $\mathbb{F}_2$ whatsoever.

Comment: Simply formulated category questions can be tough!

Comment: Maybe this is obvious but If one works with complete boolean algebras, then it is indeed the case that epimorphisme are surjective. The proof I know use that all maps between boolean locales are open maps and then that all open monomorphisms of locales are open inclusion. I'm not sure what happen when one restrict to bolean algebras that are only countably complete.

Comment: I think I agree that Stone duality settles the Boolean case (probably there are multiple ways to argue). Then [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3204727/284272) [two](https://mathoverflow.net/q/158208/82179) questions might be relevant if you want to try to generalise such an approach.

Comment: Would nonstandard models over a maximal $\sigma$-filter help?

Comment: @LSpice another example where homomorphisms to $2=\mathbf{F}_2$ don't suffice: take $X$ uncountable of cardinal $\aleph_1$ (or any uncountable cardinal not too huge), so that every $\sigma$-complete ultrafilter on $X$ is principal. Let $\mathcal{B}=2^X$ be the power set of $X$, and $\mathcal{B}_0$ be its $\sigma$-subalgebra consisting of countable and co-countable subsets. Since every $\sigma$-continuous homomorphism $2^X\to 2$ is principal, it is determined by its restriction to $\mathcal{B}_0$. In this precise case I don't know if the inclusion of $\mathcal{B}_0$ is an epimorphism.

Comment: @SimonHenry what are you stating exactly? You seem to mean some statement on epimorphisms (namely that they are surjective) in a subcategory of the given category, whose objects are complete BAs. But do you mean the full subcategory (with morphisms being $\sigma$-complete) or the non-full subcategory with morphism being only complete ones.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn one can be even more precise in BAs: the maximal proper subalgebras [I mean every subalgebra to be unital] are precisely those obtained from a surjective homomorphism onto the BA $\mathbf{F}_2\times\mathbf{F}_2$ by pulling back the diagonal, and every proper subalgebra is contained in a maximal one. Topologically such a maximal subalgebra corresponds to identifying two points in the Stone space.

Comment: @YCor : I meant in the category of complete boolean algebras, whose morphisms preserves arbitrary supremum and infimum. It is equivalent to the category of Boolean frames, which is why my comment mention locales.

Comment: It looks very stupid, but is there an immediate way to see that if a $\sigma$-BA $A$ has $|A|>2$, then the canonical inclusion $\mathbf{F}_2\to A$ is not an epimorphism of $\sigma$-BAs? (that is, there exists a $\sigma$-BA $B$ and two distinct $\sigma$-complete homomorphisms $A\to B$)

Comment: @YCor: the two canonical inclusions from $A$ to the free product $A \otimes A$ of $\sigma$-algebras should do the trick, though annoyingly I am not able to show that these two inclusions are actually distinct (I only know how to construct the free product by some general abstract nonsense that makes it very hard to actually say anything about this product).  Perhaps this is merely a reformulation of the problem.

Comment: More generally, the two canonical inclusions from ${\mathcal B}$ to the amalgamated free product (or coproduct?) ${\mathcal B} \otimes_{{\mathcal B}_0} {\mathcal B}$ should be in some sense the universal counterexample, but showing that these inclusions are distinct when ${\mathcal B}_0 \subsetneq {\mathcal B}$ seems as hard as the original problem (and might even be equivalent to it).  In principle Loomis-Sikorski duality should convert this to a more geometric problem, but I have not had luck with this approach so far.

Comment: Unless I miss something, if $B\otimes_{B_0}B$ is the amalgamated sum in the obvious categorical sense, then it seems immediate that these are reformulations of the problem, namely equivalence between (a) the two canonical maps $B\to B\otimes_{B_0}B$ are equal (b) $B_0\subset B$ is an epimorphism. This equivalence seems to hold in an arbitrary category with an arrow $B_0\to B$, provided the amalgamated sum exists. These conditions also imply: (c) each of the canonical arrows $B\to B\otimes_{B_0}B$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @YCor For your first example we can consider the algebra of subsets of $X \times X$, modulo the relation that two subsets are equal if their restrictions to $Y \times Y$ are equal for any cocountable $Y$. This admits two maps from the power set of $X$, which both send countable sets to the empty set and cocountable ones to the whole space. But these two maps aren't equal since a subset of $X$ which is neither countable nor cocountable is sent to two different things.

Comment: In the category of topological spaces, the inclusion map from a proper dense subset into its "mother space" is epi, but not surjective - for instance $\iota: \mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{R}$ in the Euclidean topology. Could such a construction be used in the context of $\sigma$-algebras?

Comment: @Simon Henry Lagrange's paper *Amalgamation and Epimorphisms in m-Complete Boolean Algebras* shows that, for any infinite cardinal $m$ or $m$=arbitrary, the category of $m$-complete Boolean algebras with $m$-complete morphisms has the strong amalgamation property, which always implies that epis are surjective.

Comment: @ Badam Baplan Do you have a copy of this paper?

Comment: Will anyone arrest me if I [link](https://scihub.wikicn.top/10.1007/BF02485738) to the paper?

Comment: @BadamBaplan: you could answer the question properly (not in a comment) to collect the points and fame.

Comment: @Andrej Bauer Yes, I was wondering why he didn't post his comment as an answer. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @TerryTao is there a reason you're choosing the terminology "$\sigma$-algebra"? I'm not from this field, but I understand that this is widely referred as "$\sigma$-complete BAs", and hence could be called "category of $\sigma$-complete BAs". I think I learnt on this site that there are $\sigma$-complete BAs that cannot be "realized as $\sigma$-algebras", that is, $\sigma$-algebras usually refers to those $\sigma$-complete BAs consisting of subsets of a set, in a way compatible with countable supremums.

Comment: I was not entirely serious about points and fame, but I was serious about answering the question because that would make the answer better documented and more visible.

Comment: An alternativ proof could try to use a Stone duality that is "between" those for Stone spaces and for [Stonean spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Stonean+space)

Comment: I had every intention of posting an answer but then... I fell asleep.  I'm not above points and fame. I'll write something up shortly.

Comment: @BadamBaplan Yes, please post this as an answer and I will happily accept it!

Comment: @YCor Thanks for the notational clarification.  I have tended to use the terminology "concrete $\sigma$-algebras" and "abstract $\sigma$-algebras" for what you refer to as "$\sigma$-algebras" and "$\sigma$-complete Boolean algebras" but I agree that the latter notation is less confusing.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$

A 1974 paper of R. Lagrange, [*Amalgamation and epimorphisms in $\mathfrak{m}$-complete Boolean algebras*](https://scihub.wikicn.top/10.1007/BF02485738) (Algebra Universalis 4 (1974), 277–279, [DOI link](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02485738)), settled this affirmatively.  In the cited paper, Lagrange shows that for any infinite cardinal $\mathfrak{m}$, the category of $\mathfrak{m}$-complete Boolean algebras with $\mathfrak{m}$-complete morphisms has the strong amalgamation property, which implies that epimorphisms are surjective.  He remarks that the proof works just as well for complete Boolean algebras, and I'd also add that it can be adapted for plain old Boolean algebras.  If I understand your meaning of an abstract $\sigma$-algebra correctly, this is the result you are after.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a concrete category so that we can meaningfully talk about epimorphisms being surjective.

$\mathcal{C}$ is said to have the **strong amalgamation property** if for every span $C \xleftarrow{f} A \xrightarrow{g} B$ of monomorphisms (aka amalgam), there exists an object $D \in \mathcal{C}$, and a commutative diagram of monomorphisms 
$$
\begin{CD}
A @> g>> B\\
@VfVV  @Vg'VV \\
C @>f'>> D,
\end{CD}
$$

such that $g'(B) \cap f'(C) = g'g(A) = f'f(A)$

Further restrict attention to a variety of algebraic structures, so that being a monomorphism is equivalent to mapping underlying sets injectively and every morphism canonically factors as a surjection followed by a monomorphism.  Then the strong amalgamation property immediately implies that epis are surjective (see the corollary in Lagrange's paper).

I think this is a good — or at least thought-provoking — approach to addressing your question in light of your bounty comment that you are "looking for a canonical answer."  For varieties, we see that the solution to the strong amalgamation problem always supplies a canonical non-unique extension: given a proper monomorphism $A \rightarrow B$, we get the strong amalgamation $D$ of $B \leftarrow A \rightarrow B$ together with distinct monomorphisms(!) $B \rightarrow D$ that agree on $A$.

Moreover, the solution to the strong amalgamation problem might be considered canonical in and of itself.  Basically, Lagrange's method is a three-part construction: (1) Embed in the best coproduct available, which is in the ambient category of Boolean algebras (2) quotient that coproduct in order to force the desired intersection property of strong amalgamation (which has the awesome effect of restoring morphisms to our actual category) (3) Complete this quotiented coproduct, so that the whole embedding is now in-category. In other words, *do the best you can with the coproduct you have... and then error-correct in the only sensible way*.  I guess that feels canonical.

On this last point, it might be interesting to compare this construction with solutions to the strong amalgamation problem in other varieties, in particular (finite) groups and Lie Algebras over fields.

Comment: "A 1974 paper of Lagrange...": the start of this answer is already very exciting! :)

Comment: @SamHopkins this is just a quite frequent surname, like Newton, Pascal, etc.

Comment: trivial typo, I think: $f'(A)$ should be $f'(C)$, no?

Comment: @YemonChoi  Certainly yes, thanks to you for noticing and to YCor for editing.